# Hibernate tools schemaexport without destroying current data

Tags: hibernate-tools

I'm doing an `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2dll.SchemaExportTask` as part of my compile/build script (it is ant with hibernate4 plugin, if it is important).

Everything works wonderfully, except one:

It destroys all data!

What I want, is realistically a simple database dump, an equivalent of "`pg_dump --all`" or like. It doesn't matter, if it is based on the xml configuration, or on the current database.

I don't want any modification on the real db, and particularly don' want any actually executed drop/create operations.

Is it possible anyhow in the sphere of the hibernate tools jars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this. Not the hibernate tools did the db-destroy, but hibernate at initialization. Setting `hibernate.hbm2dll.auto` to `update` fixed everything.